# Hi guys, I am not being able to install rosbridge on a Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: ros, rosbridge-suite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is what I get on `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rosbridge-suite`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-rosbridge-suite
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229014/hi-guys,-i-am-not-being-able-to-install-rosbridge-on-a-raspberry-pi-2./) by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2016-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [status page](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_indigo_arm.html) shows that rosbridge_suite is available in the repository.

Is your Pi 2 running Ubuntu 14.04? Is the rest of your ROS install on the Pi 2 from apt, according to the [UbuntuARM](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM) instructions? Are you running ROS Indigo?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) on 2016-03-14**:
No, I am running pure raspbian wheezy. Isn't rosbridge available for raspbian ?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-14**:
If you installed the rest of ROS from source, you'll have to install rosbridge from source too.

**Comment by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) on 2016-03-15**:
How do I do it ? Please guide me through the steps. And also the rosauth part. Sorry for being a complete newbie.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-15**:
Which install guide did you use to install ROS?

**Comment by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) on 2016-03-16**:
I installed Indigo version from the official tutorial on installing ROS on raspberry pi. [http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi]

**Comment by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) on 2016-03-16**:
I figured it out. It built rosbridge_server from source. Seems we also have to take care of the dependencies such as python-bson for rosauth. Thanks anyways.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-16**:
Yes. the final step of the raspbian install guide discusses how to add additional packages from source.